# "Cannot Connect to Database Server" error connecting from MySQL Workbench to SiteGround MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

*Situation:*
I am trying to connect to my SiteGround server MySQL database directly from my local machine using MySQL Workbench. I am positive that the connection properties are entered correctly as the connection works if I am connected to Network A (phone data plan). But with Network B, the connection failed.

- I allowed remote access to my server from my Network B IP, in fact, I allowed all IPs just for testing, therefore Network A is working.
- I checked if there is any setting that blocks the port from my router and modem in Network B, but I found nothing.
- I tried running netstat: nothing with port 3306.
- I tried running telnet: "connect failed"

*Question:*
I am suspecting that my ISP has blocked the outgoing port 3306? Is there anything I can do to "unblock" it?
Or is there any workaround for connecting to my server database?

*My connection set up screenshot:*
[image: 1]

*Error screenshot:*
[image: 2]

Thank you in advance for your time and help!!

Comment: besides allowing all connections which can be dangerous, you alos need to grant permission for the user

Comment: I believe the user has permission as it worked when I was connected to a different network.